# Why is everything returning true in function javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, return

The question is: Create a function that checks if we need to order more candy. If the inStock is less than the weeklyAverage, return true; otherwise, return false. No matter what I do to this function, however, I can't get it to return properly. It returns true (correctly) for the for the first two candies, but also returns true for the last two, when they should be false. Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
let inventory = [
  { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
  { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
  { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
  { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
];

// write the shouldWeOrderThisCandy function
function shouldWeOrderThisCandy(x, i) {
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].inStock < x[i].weeklyAverage) {
      return true;
    }else {
      return false;
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `return` exits your loop on the very first iteration

Comment: The "correct" way to do this would be `const shouldWeOrderThisCandy = Object.fromEntries(inventory.map(entry=>[entry.candy, entry.inStock < entry.weeklyAverage]));` - this will yield an object with candy names as keys and booleans as values indicating if that candy should be restocked.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys! This is for a practice review for a bootcamp prep, so I'm just trying to get it to match and pass their solutions/expectations. Right now, it just tells me if my function passed or failed through each iteration of the loop

Comment: How do you call the `shouldWeOrderThisCandy()` function?

Comment: shouldWeOrderThisCandy();

Comment: Use `every()` ....

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking at this, you don't need the else conditional.

put:

```
return inventory[i].inStock < inventory[i].weeklyAverage
```

inside the `if` body, and it will return either `true` or `false` for every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get list of candies to order.

```
var shouldWeOrderThisCandy1 =() => inventory.filter(candyIn=> candyIn.inStock < candyIn.weeklyAverage).reduce((acc,candyIn) => { acc.push(candyIn.candy); return acc; },[]);
shouldWeOrderThisCandy1();
```